# Invalid topo name mytopo

Tags: mininet

i got the following error when trying to run my costumed topology on mininet.
i am running the command :

```
sudo mn --custom Q1_a.py --topo=mytopo
```

and i get the error:

**Caught exception. Cleaning up...
Exception: Invalid topo name mytopo**

this is my python file Q1_a.py

```js
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.util import dumpNodeConnections
from mininet.log import setLogLevel

TOPOS = {'mytopo' : (lambda : mytopo(4))}

class mytopo(Topo):
    "Single switch connected to n hosts."
    def build(self, n=4):
        switch1 = self.addSwitch('s1')
 switch2=self.addSwitch('s2')
        host1 = self.addHost('h%s' % (1))
        self.addLink(host1, switch1)
        host2 = self.addHost('h%s' % (2))
        self.addLink(host2, switch1)
        host3 = self.addHost('h%s' % (3))
        self.addLink(host3, switch2)
        host4 = self.addHost('h%s' % (4))
        self.addLink(host4, switch2) 
    
def Q1_a():
    "Create and test a simple network"
    topo = mytopo(n=4)
    net = Mininet(topo)
    //net.start()
    //net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Tell mininet to print useful information
    setLogLevel('info')
    Q1_a()
```

i will be glad for help with this one

Answer (score 0):

I called the file test.py and I used the code that you wrote, except for line 26 and 27, I used # to comment.

If I run it works:

```
mn --custom  test.py --topo=mytopo
```

test.py

```
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.util import dumpNodeConnections
from mininet.log import setLogLevel

TOPOS = {'mytopo' : (lambda : mytopo(4))}

class mytopo(Topo):
    "Single switch connected to n hosts."
    def build(self, n=4):
        switch1 = self.addSwitch('s1')
    switch2=self.addSwitch('s2')
        host1 = self.addHost('h%s' % (1))
        self.addLink(host1, switch1)
        host2 = self.addHost('h%s' % (2))
        self.addLink(host2, switch1)
        host3 = self.addHost('h%s' % (3))
        self.addLink(host3, switch2)
        host4 = self.addHost('h%s' % (4))
        self.addLink(host4, switch2)

def Q1_a():
    "Create and test a simple network"
    topo = mytopo(n=4)
    net = Mininet(topo)
    #net.start()
    #net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Tell mininet to print useful information
    setLogLevel('info')
    Q1_a()
```